# concatenating sequences in 4clojure function

Tags: clojure

I just finished 4clojure [Problem 60](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/60), here's the code for my first program with the problem description:

```
;;Write a function which behaves like reduce, but returns each intermediate
;;value of the reduction. Your function must accept either two or three arguments,
;;and the return sequence must be lazy.
(fn red
  ([fun sq]
     (red fun (first sq) (rest sq)))
  ([fun acum sq]
   (if (empty? sq) acum
     (cons acum (lazy-seq (red fun (fun acum (first sq)) (rest sq)))))))
```

The core of the function occurs one line bellow the if, I just return the initial value followed by applying it to the next element in the sequence. But it fails for the second test case involving vectors:

```
user=> (red conj [1] [2 3 4])
([1] [1 2] [1 2 3] 1 2 3 4);; it should be ([1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4])
```

It took me some time to realize that the problem was the `cons` which just adds the `vector` `[1 2 3 4]` as it were the rest of the list instead as a single element.

What I did is to convert `cons` to `concat` and `acum` to `[acum]` and it worked:

```
(fn red
  ([fun sq]
     (red fun (first sq) (rest sq)))
  ([fun acum sq]
   (if (empty? sq) [acum]
     (concat [acum] (lazy-seq
                     (red fun (fun acum (first sq)) (rest sq)))))))
```

Don't ask me why but it seems to me kind of inelegant, the other solutions didn't use `concat` neither.

The question is, considering the first function as it is, what function/macro does the work without modifying the code too much.

Comment: As corrected by @Ankur, `(red + ())` returns `[nil]`. To be consistent with `reduce` and `reductions`, `red` had better return `[(fun)]` when `sq` is empty in the two-arguments invocation.

Answer (score 3):

In the `if` true case return `[acum]` instead of `acum`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of concat if you take cons instead. Cons is lazy (see the discussion of cons vs. conj on Stack Overflow):

```
(defn my-reductions
  ([f sq] (my-reductions f (first sq) (rest sq)))
  ([f init sq]
    (if (empty? sq)
      (list init) 
      (cons init (lazy-seq (my-reductions f (f init (first sq)) (rest sq))))
    )
  )
)
```

Btw: This code passes the 4Clojure tests, but doesn't quite behave like reductions in all cases:

```
(my-reductions + [])  
(nil)  
(reductions + [])  
(0)
```